# Next step for learning asp.net after read book beginning asp.net 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, ajax

I'm started to learn asp.net and untill now i finish the book beginning asp.net 4, what should i read now ? (css - jquery - javascript - ajax - ...)

Comment: `what should i read now ?` : you could start with the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: maybe you should try to build a website, and read about whatever skill you miss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you pick a problem to give you focus (something small such as a to-do list application) and start writing some code.

Doing this will highlight any gaps that you currently have giving you a basis for more research.

While webforms is 'easy' and handles much of the http stack for you, I agree with Ed R about going down the ASP.NET MVC 3 route.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest working though the [Getting started with ASP.NET MVC3 tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3) . In addition to ASP.NET it covers MVC3 and Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing after ASP.Net is HTML and mixing this with Javascript or for start JQuery library to make fine pages. Its so fast and flexible.
have good time!